# Android Alert Dialog help to customize for API >=8

Tags: android, api, android-alertdialog

Hiee guys, I need to make my alertDialog look like this :

for API >=8.

Please let me know how to go about it. And is it possible to create this for all android versions>=8

[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use Dialog instead and do everything as you want.

Comment: @Android-Developer -  
Can you please help me with a start code? Is it like I create I create a layout.xml and then do something like setContentView()?

Comment: I cant understand why people downvote legitimate questions? blows my mind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do everything you want using `Dialog`.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(FingerPaintActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // no title 
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation; // this is used for custom animation when dialog is showing and hiding 
dialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomLayout, null)); // here is your custom layout
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width-50, (height-100)); // set height / width
dialog.show();
```

The layout which you have to add is `R.layout.myCustomLayout` and after that you can get your views declared in that layout as shown below (for example a button):

```
Button myOkBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.myOkBtn);
myOkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
});
```

and that's all.

**P.S.** As you can see I have some extra things added like custom animations while Dialog is opening and closed and width and height.

Comment: I tried this but no dialog is being displayed ? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: at the end you have to put dialog.show(); I include it on the answer too..sorry for missing it

Comment: I added dialog.show()..not able to set proper width and height..how to do a wrap_content?

Comment: you have to play with it yourself, calculating the size depending on the screen width and height

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to customize the theme you can use
`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( new ContextThemeWrapper(activity,R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme));`

"activity" is a reference to your activity and "CustomAlertDialogTheme" is a customized theme that you can set the colors in it.

Comment: can I set the color of title area as yellow, body as white and a line above the buttons using the above?

Comment: yes, just like customizing other themes. take a look at this [link](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=309) and [link](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)